# To display Number With 2 Decimal Places

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net

I have a field in datatable .If 1000 is the value in it, i want to display it as 1000.00.Then if user changes to 1000.50 it should display as it is.Is there anyway to do this?Can anybody help?

Answer (score 42):

**Sample Code:**

```
Dim bigNumber As Decimal = 1234567.123456
Console.WriteLine("F2: " & bigNumber.ToString("F2"))
Console.WriteLine("N2: " & bigNumber.ToString("N2"))
```

**Output:**

```
F2: 1234567.12
N2: 1,234,567.12
```

Answer (score 10):

Just `ToString` will not necessarily work in all situations. If you were to format the decimal fields of a data row, the following would be required:

```
Format(datarow("field"), "C") ' for currency
Format(datarow("field"), "N2") ' for 2 decimal places
```

This approach will work on all numbers.

Comment: Better than ToString function. Good one.

Answer (score 6):

There is a good chance that you want to display currency, so do this:

```
1000m.ToString("C"); // Will show $1000.00, $1000,00 etc depending on culture
// OR just
1000m.ToString("N2"); 1000m.ToString("F2"); // For plain numbers: 1000.00, 1000,00
```

Answer (score 5):

can be accomplish like..

```
decimal ab = 50;
ab.ToString("####0.00");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
dbNumber.ToString("N2")
```

where dbNumber is the variable to convert.