# Show only 2 decimals in result

Tags: vb.net, decimal

I would like to show only 2 decimal numbers in the result, but I don't know how.
Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim data1 As Double
    Dim data2 As Double

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        data1 = TextBox1.Text
        data2 = TextBox2.Text
        Label4.Text = (data1 / data2) * 100 & "Liter / 100 Km"
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
        If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57 Then
            e.Handled = True
            MsgBox("Csak szám", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Hiba")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox2_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyPress
        If Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57 Then
            e.Handled = True
            MsgBox("Csak szám", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Hiba")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score -1):

data1.ToString("C"); // Will show $1000.00, $1000,00 etc depending on culture
// OR just
data1.ToString("N2"); 1000m.ToString("F2"); // For plain numbers: 1000.00, 1000,00

copied from 
[To display Number With 2 Decimal Places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304132/to-display-number-with-2-decimal-places)

Comment: Thanks, but how i can insert in my code? Sorry, but i am beginner.